# Can I return a string value via angular custom validation method

Tags: angular, rxjs

Here is my **working** validation method (but notice where I try to sneak in res):

```
  checkIfEmailExists(email: string): Observable<object | null> {
    return this.store.pipe(
      select(selectAssigneeNameByEmail(email)),
      debounceTime(500),
      take(1),
      map(name => {
        return res ? { alreadyExists: true, name } : null;
      })
    );
```

and here is where I call it in component (and would like to also consume the name from above but how? Pipe?:

```
 alreadyExists(control: AbstractControl): object {
    return this.emailAlreadyExistsValidator.checkIfEmailExists(control.value)
 }
```

html:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="form.get('email').hasError('alreadyExists')">email already associated with {{name}}</mat-error>
```

So, I just want to be able to use res from above to say, sorry that email is already associated with {{name}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since your error object returned from the validation already returns the name (via `{alreadyExists: true, name}` object), you can simply get it from the form:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="form.hasError('alreadyExists', 'email')">
  email already associated with {{ form.getError('name', 'email') }}
</mat-error>
```

A good idea IMO would be to return the associated error message straight from the validator:

```
return res ? { alreadyExists: `E-mail already associated with ${name}` } : null;
```

And then on the HTML:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="form.getError('alreadyExists', 'email'); let errorMsg">
  {{ errorMsg }}
</mat-error>
```